# what api is used to update k8s resource label?

Tags: kubernetes

k8s swagger: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/master/src/gen/swagger.json

What operation the command `kubectl label service service1 --overwrite x=3` uses?

I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running your command with "--v=8" which will show you the complete request and response to API server.

Example: kubectl label service service1 --overwrite x=3 --v=8